# How to link two forms to same XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, forms

I have a question about linking two forms and get all texts from textboxes and store to same xml element.

For example

Form 1

NAME, LAST NAME, NUMBER

Form 2

ID NUMBER, BIRTH DATE, CITY

So when we click SAVE on Form 2, strings in Form 1 have to get the data from Form2 textboxes and when I hit SAVE in FORM 1, All data to be saved in xml.

Also, When I select a user in listview, I want to transfer all data to textboxes in two forms.

Hope that anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear as in where your problem lies (and what have you done so far to solve it), but I will try to help as much as I can:

**XML Part**

The easiest way to do it is to create a class that will serve as DTO (Data Transfer Object) if you don't already have it and put there **all** the fields that you have (NAME, LAST NAME, NUMBER **and** ID NUMBER, BIRTH DATE, CITY)

Afterwards you need to tell the xml serializer how to serialize that class. You can see [that](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14064/Using-the-XmlSerializer-Attributes) article for the purpose. I will provide a simple example here

```
    [XmlRoot("Sample")]
    public class SampleDto
    {
        private string name;
        //more fields here

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        //more properties here

    }
```

**Forms Part**

Now that you have the DTO ready, you can send the **same** object to **both** Forms that you have and set the values to the respective textfield. For example:

```
SampleDto data;

//initialize data somewhere

nameTextBox.Text = data.Name;
//do the same for the rest
```

Alternatively you can use [data binding to an object](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial)

Hope that helps.